# Can't convert from NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I can't convert my NSString to NSDate. here's the code:

```
+ (NSDate *) stringToNSDate: (NSString *) dateString{
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@ datefromstring: %@", dateString, dateFromString);
return dateFromString;
}

//dateFromString is nil.
```

What should I do? Thanks!

btw, dateString will always contain a string-ed date in this format: "2012/02/10 08:01:25 +0000"

Comment: Show us what `dateString` contains when the method is called would be a good start.

Comment: dateString will always contain a string-ed date in this format: "2012/02/10 08:01:25 +0000"

Comment: Can you give an example of your datestring?

Comment: @mbh: 2012/02/10 08:01:25 +0000

Comment: @acecapades: Your date string has slashes but you've told the formatter that it has dashes.

Comment: btw another question, what's the easiest way to convert a date with this format "2012/02/10 08:01:25 +0000" to "2012-02-10T08:01:25Z"? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

Comment: yeah you're right @mbh. I've addedd ZZZ though, because without that, it still doesn't work. Thanks!    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

Answer (score 3):

From the information you've given, the problem appears to be that your `dateString` separates the date components with slashes (`\`), but your date formatter is expecting dashes (`-`).

---

#### Edit

To answer your other question, you can use [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6).

For example:

```
NSString *date1 = @"2012/12/10 ...";
NSString *date2 = [date1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"-"];
```

Note that this will replace every `/` with `-`, so just be careful about timezones etc.

Comment: btw another question, what's the easiest way to convert a date with this format "2012/02/10 08:01:25 +0000" to "2012-02-10T08:01:25Z"? Thanks a lot!